# Unable to use fwrite properly

Tags: c, cs50

I'm unable to figure out how to use fwrite here. I'm getting a segmentation fault. Is there any other way I can write 0x00 to rgbtRed, rgbtBlue and rgbtGreen? I've looked up online, but couldn't find the right way to do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef uint8_t  BYTE;

typedef struct
{
    BYTE rgbtBlue;
    BYTE rgbtGreen;
    BYTE rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;

int main (void)
{

    RGBTRIPLE triple;
    /*code which opens a bmp file, copies it and exports it to another 
    file based on the changes which I ask it.
    I'm trying to set R's (of RGB) value to 0 to see if that solves  
    the problem. I'm trying to figure out how to set the value to 0*/

    fwrite(&triple.rgbtRed, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, 0x00);


}
```

Comment: [`fwrite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) is for writing to a file (refer to the example code in the linked page eg.). Are you trying to write to a file, or do you simply want to fill a struct instance ?

Comment: @sanderDeDycker I'm trying to write to a file.

Comment: fouurth argument is valid FILE *, not 'data-what-you-want'

Comment: you've added a comment describing the rest of your code - instead, please add your actual code, so it's clear what you mean. If the code is too long, then cut it down to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JacekCz Oh! So, if I make a .txt document, and write only 0x00 in it. Will I be able to input 0x00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fourth argument of fwrite should be opened for writing FILE

Giving zero has result in exception

```
FILE * aFileYouWrite = fopen("afilename.xyz","wb");
memset(&triple, 0, sizeof triple); 
fwrite(&triple.rgbtRed, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, aFileYouWrite );
```

Answer (score 2):

`fwrite` is for writing to a file, but you want to set memory to zero, which is not quite the same thing.

With this line of code, the whole `triple` structure is set to zero.

```
memset(&triple, 0, sizeof triple);
```

Comment: It is not answer in context of problem.

Comment: @Jacek Cz, "unable to figure out how to use fwrite here"?